# Пунктуация в предложении со вставной конструкцией

Tags: пунктуация

"Выскочила я на минуточку на улицу – тут у нас в нашем же доме под низом кондитерская – взяла десять штучек песочного пирожного и прихожу..." (Леск.)

Такой пример приводится у Розенталя. Разве здесь не нужна запятая перед вторым тире?

Answer (score 1):

Розенталь пишет, что более  сильным выключающим знаком являются скобки, поэтому в данном предложении уместнее использовать скобки, а после закрывающей скобки - запятую. Есть еще правило о поглощении одних знаков препинания другими. Тире - более сильный знак, поэтому,возможно, в Вашем варианте после тире нет запятой, т.к. она поглощена тире.