# «Неважно, кто вы, чем занимаетесь _ мы поможем» Какой знак?

Tags: пунктуация

*Неважно, кто вы, чем занимаетесь _ мы поможем.*

На месте подчёркивания, похоже, должно стоять тире. Но мне кажется, что это не совсем правильно. Так как же правильно?

Answer (score 5):

***Неважно, кто вы, чем занимаетесь, — мы поможем.***

Это сложное предложение с бессоюзной связью, в котором смысловым центром является последняя часть "***мы поможем***".

[**§ 45. Тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151) (Розенталь)

> В бессоюзном сложном предложении **тире** между частями обычно ставится в тех случаях, когда **основная часть высказывания** (соответствующая иногда главной части сложноподчиненного предложения) **содержится во второй части** сложного предложения, а **первая часть** (соответствующая придаточной части) **имеет подчиненное по смыслу значение**, указывая время или условие совершения действия, о котором идет речь во второй части, иногда причину, уступку и т. д.

**Запятая** перед тире закрывает однородные придаточные первого безличного предложения "***Неважно***".

Также данное предложение может подойти к случаю, в котором используется **запятая и тире как единый знак препинания**.

См. [**§ 46. Запятая и тире в бессоюзном сложном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_46.htm) (Розенталь)

Comment: @behemothus  Случай с "переломом" конструкции довольно размытая (относительная) формулировка, которая может восприниматься по-разному (субъективно).  _...структурный поворот от предшествующей части под некоторым, большим или меньшим, “углом”..._ На мой взгляд, это "неожиданный" поворот.

Comment: @behemothus  Изначально я не хотел упоминать о едином знаке, понимая, что это может вызвать вопросы и несогласие. Потом всё-таки решился дать ссылку без пояснения в самом ответе, чтобы посмотреть реакцию.

Comment: *Потом всё-таки решился дать ссылку без пояснения в самом ответе* - вы напрасно сделали. Обязательно надо аргументировать то, что спорно.

Comment: А еще совет: не спешите отвечать двоечникам. Пусть хоть иногда сам и мозгами пошевелят.

Comment: По поводу знака. Если принять, что тут есть условия для единого знака (в чемя сомневаюсь, как вы поняли), то да, обсуждать тут особо нечего.  Что же касается самого сочетания запятой с тире, то тут все крайне запутано.  Я не уверен, что запятая тут должна остаться, если не применять правило единого знака.  Проблема в том, что в некоторых случаях знаки "поглощают" друг  друга. Вот когда это следует из правил - не могу сказать. Я только тут раза три уже пытался внести хоть какую-то ясность... Посмотрите для общей картины.

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445477

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10706

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17989 -  и еще много где..

Answer (score 1):

***Неважно, кто вы, чем занимаетесь – мы поможем.***

Пояснение

1) Тире ставится в бессоюзном сложном предложении (БСП) со значением **уступки**, причем уступительная часть находится **в препозиции**. Уступительная часть – это отдельное сложноподчиненное предложение с двумя однородными изъяснительными придаточными.

2) Постановка тире  при уступительных отношениях соответствует **правилам Розенталя,** также это верно для всех предложений  такого вида (время – событие, условие – событие). В этом случае предложение интонационно делится **на две части, противопоставленные** друг другу.

Розенталь, п. 4, 5 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

3) В заданном предложении важно также отметить такую деталь, как **однородные придаточные**, на которые должно падать  ударение (что соответствует **перечислительной** интонации).  Это тоже надо учитывать при составлении интонационной модели предложения.

2) Вопрос стоит **только о запятой, закрывающей придаточную часть.**  Подобный пример можно найти у у Розенталя: ***Пишут, чтобы мы обязАтельно приезжали — будут встречАть.*** Здесь также изъяснительная часть на закрыта запятой перед тире.

Розенталь, п. 7 http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

3) В тоже время надо отметить, что  этот вопрос **не рассмотрен** в правилах (на уровне грамматики)  достаточно ясно,  а  в  современной художественной литературе явно присутствуют **два разных решения** (часто даже у одного и того же автора).

4) Отсутствие запятой в данном случае я связываю с необходимостью выразить **смысловое отношение** между частями предложение в БСП, где отсутствуют союзы, а главным средством для этого является **интонация**. Запятая же помешает **четкому интонационному делению** предложения на две противопоставленные части.